# different designs for different screen resolutions

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a client who wants their website converted to responsive. They send me the design for desktop version, iPad version and mobile version. The design have variations. I am trying to tell them you need only one design and responsive web sites are done using fluid grids which will fall in place depending on the screen size. Am I correct in saying this.

Again what will you say is a perfect responsive design

Answer (score 1):

Your client is correct, imagine for example they're site starting from a  desktop perspective it has a fixed navigation at the top of the page, below it is a image carousel for there feature images and then below that is the main content area. On the right they have a sidebar with sections for a facebook fan box, email newsletter sign up form. Lastly is the footer with the copyright and social icons.

The image carousel looks great on the desktop and ipad but the images scaling down to a 420px screen width for a iphone is sometimes not necessary. This is where hierarchy and media queries come in, they are used to help you display only the most important elements on the page. I like bootstrap it's one of the most popular front end framework. It includes HTML, CSS, and JS.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use zurb foundation or getbootstrap. But think like this: If your main focus is mobile I prefer foundation, but if your main focus is desktop, both options are great

Comment: You tried to use some of this? If yes, please mark it as an aswer if it solved your problem.